# Can i use margin auto, and left with transform at the same time?

Tags: css

At a webpage i observed that there is a problem with positioning, so i started remove some css to see what is a problem. The problem is that navbar has 1px on the left from the edge of screen. To be honest i dont now what is deeper level of this. When i remove last two lines everything looks ok so my question is:

can i use margin auto, and left with transform at the same time?

```
.navbar {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85) !important;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 1051;
  max-width: 1920px;
  margin: auto;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. However, the margin won't do anything, since your position is fixed. The last two lines just center the navbar, which will have no visual effect until your screen is wider than 1920px and the `max-width` kicks in.

Comment: now i checked the screen size. When i set 1921 the problem starts. so this pixel left side is coused by wrong usage of  left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);

Comment: Without the left/transform, the pixel would be on the right side. If you want the bar to stay centered, this is the correct way of using it.